# Error when building image from Dockerfile

Tags: docker

-Error when building and image from Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER Name Surname "email@gmail.com"
ENV REFRESHED_AT 2021-12-24
RUN apt-get update -yqq; apt-get -yqq install ruby ruby-dev build-essential redis-tools
RUN gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri sinatra json redis
RUN mkdir -p /opt/webapp
EXPOSE 4567
CMD [ "/opt/webapp/bin/webapp" ]
```

-The error log:

```
Step 5/8 : RUN gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri sinatra json redis
 ---> Running in 061004febbcd
Successfully installed rack-2.2.3
Successfully installed tilt-2.0.10
Successfully installed rack-protection-2.1.0
Successfully installed ruby2_keywords-0.0.5
Successfully installed mustermann-1.1.1
Successfully installed sinatra-2.1.0
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

ERROR:  Error installing redis:
    redis requires Ruby version >= 2.4.0.

Successfully installed json-2.6.1
7 gems installed
The command '/bin/sh -c gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri sinatra json redis' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

How can i install specific version of Ruby?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **code, logs, output, error messages... in the question body as code blocks**. Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in the must read help article [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask). Thanks

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you need to use the ubuntu 16.04?

if you use a newer version of ubuntu, like 20.04 it should install a newer version of Ruby.

Comment: No i am not bind to this version of Ubuntu, thank you i`ll try.

Comment: Thank you helped me, now it is ok. Changed code in Dockerfile: `RUN gem install --no-document sinatra json redis` and `FROM ubuntu:20.04`

Comment: You could also use the [prebuit Docker Hub `ruby` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby) as a base.  I'd also suggest using [Bundler](https://bundler.io) to manage gems and keep a consistent set of versions between your non-Docker build environment and your containerized installation, rather than `gem install`ing individual packages in the Dockerfile.